# Use selenium without xvfb in FreeBSD

Tags: python, selenium, freebsd

I have a problem with setting up in freebsd my code.
I try to install xvfb but don't found what packed. SO I install xephyr. And try to use it. Install and firefox. So can you help me setup my code for it?
I don't have now root access to install more stuff on the server. I can use only now pip install...
my code

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

```
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()


driver = webdriver.Firefox()


driver.get("https://www.verivox.de/stromvergleich/vergleich/#/?plz=10555&persons=on&usage=3500&bonus=OnlyCompliant&profile=H0&product=electricity&source=1&q=WzYsMCwxLDEsMSwxLDEsMiwyMCwwLDEsNzQxMTIyLCI3MTA4NSIsMSwyNDAsMjQwLDM1MDAsMCwwLDAsOTk5LC0xLC0xLC0xLDAsMCwiVG90YWxDb3N0cyIsIkFzY2VuZGluZyIsIk5vbmUiLDM4LCJBbm51YWxDb3N0VmlldyIsMF0%3D&partnerid=1")



allheader=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"li[class='result-item'] .result-name-area>.result-name")))
for header in allheader:
     print("Header: " + header.text)

display.stop()
```

My error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dvodev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/easyprocess/__init__.py", line 169, in start
    cmd, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr, cwd=self.cwd, env=self.env,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Xvfb': 'Xvfb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "skriptas.py", line 9, in <module>
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
  File "/home/dvodev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py", line 58, in __init__
    **kwargs
  File "/home/dvodev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/xvfb.py", line 54, in __init__
    extra_args=extra_args,
  File "/home/dvodev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/abstractdisplay.py", line 87, in __init__
    helptext = get_helptext(program)
  File "/home/dvodev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/util.py", line 10, in get_helptext
    p.call()
  File "/home/dvodev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/easyprocess/__init__.py", line 141, in call
    self.start().wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/dvodev/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/easyprocess/__init__.py", line 174, in start
    raise EasyProcessError(self, "start error")
easyprocess.EasyProcessError: start error <EasyProcess cmd_param=['Xvfb', '-help'] cmd=['Xvfb', '-help'] oserror=[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Xvfb': 'Xvfb' return_code=None stdout="None" stderr="None" timeout_happened=False>
```

Any idea how to solve it? Please help me.

Comment: from pyvirtualdisplay.xephyr import XephyrDisplay & display = XephyrDisplay() Check examples here https://github.com/ponty/PyVirtualDisplay/blob/master/tests/test_core.py#L88

Comment: ```File "script.py", line 11, in <module>
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
NameError: name 'Display' is not defined``` im checking right now examples

Comment: You can use firefox in headless mode without xvfb or xephyr . Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Headless_mode

Comment: Where i can found geckodriver?

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: I upload file (geckodriver) to the folder where is script. Then i put path, ```'\usr\home\myuser\scipts\geckodriver.exe'``` , and get error like this ```File "skriptas.py", line 10    driver = Firefox(executable_path='\usr\home\myuser\scipts\geckodriver.exe', options=options)                                     ^ SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape``` I upload 32 bits maybe here is the problem?